# Links in previews of messaging extensions in Microsoft teams apps

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've been working on a messaging extension app that goes through some database and gives cards as results. However, Microsoft teams does not seem to let me have more than 50 cards in the preview of the messaging extension. So, I am trying to create an openUrl link directly on the preview as a 50th card, or somewhere the link can be seen on the preview. My first thought was to give the last (50th) card a tap action so it takes users to the webpage I need, but I could not find any examples or helpful documentations I can use. I do not believe teams allows me to have buttons on my preview cards so that might be the only way I can do it. I am using hero cards on my preview. I need help making use of cardActions. I do not know if there are other ways to have links in the preview sections of messaging extensions, so please let me know if there is anything I might be able to use.

Comment: Currently teams doesn't support to have links in preview of the message extensions.Could you please try card actions as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions)

Comment: I had been trying to incorporate the card Actions with my hero cards, but have had no luck. Can you please show me an example of a hero card with the openUrl card action set up? I saw the examples in the documentation, but none of them show how to integrate the card Actions in the hero cards. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please try hero card actions as  documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#hero-card)?

Comment: //I have tried a lot of ways similar to this from the documentation. But none of them seem to work.
preview = CardFactory.heroCard(
                        'BotFramework Hero Card',
                        
                        CardFactory.actions([
                            {
                                type: 'openUrl',
                                title: 'Get started',
                                value: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/'
                            }
                        ])
                    );

Comment: Could You please try this code - public static ComposeExtensionAttachment Getherocard() {var heroCard = new HeroCard { Title = "BotFramework Hero Card",Subtitle = "Microsoft Bot Framework",Text = "Testing the herocard" +" This is the first hero card to practice",Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage(Url + "images/image.png") },Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "open URL", value: url) },};return heroCard.ToAttachment().ToComposeExtensionAttachment();}

Comment: It would not work. I do not think CardAction is a class; therefore, I can not create an instance of it.

Comment: Since I could not create buttons, on the preview cards, is there a way to just display a clickable URL on the preview?

Comment: CardAction is a class come from metadata to do this You need to install Microsoft.Bot.Connector for your solution.Currently teams does not support to display any URL in the preview section.